# How do I test fire-and-forget request in Java 8?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, java.util.concurrent

I have this code which is fire-and-forget that runs on another Thread that i need to test.

Here's my code.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
                executor.submit(() -> {
                    String partitionKey = format("partitionKey-%d", random.nextInt(10000));

                    String pPpageViewStreamName = this.stormConf.get(pPAGEVIEW_STREAMNAME).toString();
                    PutRecordResult putRecordResult = this.amazonKinesisClient.putRecord(pageViewStreamName,
                            wrap(gson.toJson(newMap).getBytes()),
                            partitionKey);

                    LOG.debug(format("Put Result in shardId %s with data %s: ", putRecordResult.getShardId(), newMap.toString()));
                });
```

But not my test won't work. Here's my test

FixtureGenerator fixtureGenerator = FixtureGenerator.create().buildPageViewEvent();
        Tuple tuple = MockTupleHelpers.mockTuple(fixtureGenerator.toJson());

```
    when(this.random.nextInt(10000)).thenReturn(1000);

    PutRecordResult putRecordResult = new PutRecordResult();
    putRecordResult.setShardId("shardId");
    when(this.amazonKinesisClient.putRecord(any(String.class), any(ByteBuffer.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(putRecordResult);

    bolt.execute(tuple, null);

    verify(this.amazonKinesisClient).putRecord(this.captorStreamName.capture(), this.captorData.capture(), this.captorPartitionKey.capture());

    assertThat(this.captorStreamName.getValue(), is(equalTo("pageview-ci")));
    assertThat(this.captorPartitionKey.getValue(), is(equalTo("partitionKey-1000")));
```

`bolt.execute` is the code that does fire and forget.

The error I get is this

```
Wanted but not invoked:
amazonKinesisClient.putRecord(
    <Capturing argument>,
    <Capturing argument>,
    <Capturing argument>
);
-> at io.data.bolt.EmitPageViewBoltTest.shouldEmitDataToKinesis(EmitPageViewBoltTest.java:83)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
```

It's because `amazonKinesisClient` is never invoked. I tried Thread.sleep(1000) but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. One possible approach to test this is to use an `ExecutorService` factory, that can be injected in your class under test. For the test setup, you can then use an `ExecutorService` that uses the current thread. This allows your test to test the functionality as if it's not multi threaded.
2. Another possible approach is to extract the behavior on the thread in a separate class, and test that class separately.
3. Not very ideal, but feasible, or even desirable in some circumstances is to return the `Future` from the surrounding method. In your test you can then call `get()` on the `Future` and assert its return value, and that no Exceptions have occurred.

As for your current code, you verify immediately after running the test. This creates a race condition. Sleeping can help, but you'll never get a reliable test, that is fast as well. You could stub the `amazonKinesisClient.putRecord()` to call `countDown()` on a binary `CountDownLatch` and in the test method wait for the latch with a timeout, before verifying.

You say you've already tried sleeping, and that the method did not get called. Possibly an `Exception` occurs before the method is invoked. Without more source code, I cannot tell you what that Exception may be.